# Combinations word "GRACEFUL" question

Tags: combinatorics

The total letter arrangements for the word GRACEFUL is `8!`.

The question is: What fraction of all arrangements of `GRACEFUL` have no pair of consecutive vowels?

Now the three vowels in this word are `A`, `E`, and `U`. They can appear consecutively in `3P3` ways so this can be handled in `8! / 3P3` ways. But it is also possible that any two can appear consecutively.

So would the answer be: `8! / (3P3) * 2! * 3`?

Comment: Please use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there cannot be consecutive vowels, remove two consonants (we'll add them back in shortly). We can look at the number of ways to arrange $3$ vowels and $3$ consonants, now without the restriction on consecutive vowels. There are $6\choose3$ ways to do this. For any arrangement, add one consonant between the first and second vowel, and another between the second and third.

Now assign vowels and consonants: there are $(3!)(5!)$ ways to do this. The fraction you are looking for is therefore: $$\frac{{6\choose3}(3!)(5!)}{8!}$$

Comment: Variant, inspired by Sasha's final answer: after finding $6\choose3$ as described above, now notice that there are $8\choose3$ ways in total to distribute $3$ vowels in an $8$-letter word. This gives $\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the total number of arrangements is $8!$.

I don't understand your "$8!/3P3$" to "handle" the case of all three vowels appearing consecutively: if all three vowels appear together, then there are six locations for the block of three vowels to be placed at. There are $3!$ ways of placing the vowels in the block, and $5!$ ways of placing the remaining letters in the remaining spots. That gives $6\times 3!\times 5!$ ways in which the three vowels may appear together. But this is neither equal to $8!/3P3$, nor is it equal to $8!-8!/3P3$. So I don't understand what you mean by "handling" the case, or how the case relates to $8!/3P3$.

In how many ways can at least two vowels appear together? Select the location of the block of two vowels, which can be done in $7$ different ways. Then select the vowels to appear in the block, in order: $3\times 2$. Then place the remaining six letters in the remaining six spots: $6!$. We get $7\times 6\times 6!$. But this overcounts: if the three vowels appear together, then we counted that particular arrangement twice: once when we selected the first two vowels as the block, once when we selected the last two vowels as the block.

So: the total number in which no two vowels appear together would be:
$$(\text{total number of arrangements}) - (\text{arrangements with at least two vowels together}) + (\text{arrangements will all three together}).$$

Answer (score 2):

There are 3! ways to arrange vowels. Let there be $k_1$ consonants before the first vowel, $k_2$ between the first and the second, $k_3$ between the second and the third, and $k_4$ after the third vowel. Clearly:
$$
   k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4 = 8 - 3 =5, \qquad k_1 \geqslant 0, k_4 \geqslant 0, k_2 \geqslant 1, k_3 \geqslant 1 
$$
Thus the number of arrangements:
$$
   3! \cdot 5! \sum_{k_1=0}^3 \sum_{k_2=1}^4 \sum_{k_3=1}^4 \sum_{k_4=0}^3 \delta_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4,5} = 3! \cdot 5! \cdot 20
$$
The sum can be evaluated as follows:
$$
  \sum_{k_1=0}^3 \sum_{k_2=1}^4 \sum_{k_3=1}^4 \sum_{k_4=0}^3 \delta_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4,5} = \sum_{k_1=0}^3 \sum_{k_2=0}^3 \sum_{k_3=0}^3 \sum_{k_4=0}^3 \delta_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4,3} = [z]^3 \left( \frac{1-z^4}{1-z}\right)^4 = [z]^3 \left( \frac{1}{1-z}\right)^4 = \binom{3+4-1}{3} = \binom{6}{3}
$$

The fraction is thus 
$$\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{5}{14}$$

Answer (score 0):

My answer : Arrangement of GRACEFUL have (a)F&G  appearing side by side : There are two cases for here FG or GF . For the first case consider FG as single letter V . Now we arrange V,R,A,C,E,U,L these 7 letter in 7!  ways .The same thing happen for GF  . For (a) there are total 2×7!/8! Fraction   of arrangements. (b) No pair of consecutive vowels : We solve these problem by using complementary method i.e.All arrangement of GRACEFUL - arrangement with  pair of consecutive vowels . There are 8! arrangements of GRACEFUL . We find arrangement of GRACEFUL with pair of consecutive vowels . Here we have three vowels choose 2  vowels from 3 vowels in C(3,2) ways and arrangement of these vowels in 2! ways . Remaining 5 constant,one pair of vowel and 1 vowel arrange in  7! ways . But other case happen here is GRA(EU)FLC  I.e. three consecutive vowels in arrangement of GRACEFUL .Subtract these case from arrangement of pair of consective vowels . Arrangements of three  consecutive vowels in graceful is 3!×6! . All arrangements of graceful of case (b) are 7!×C(3,2)×2!- 6!×3!/8!